# Calling PowerShell from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, powershell

I'm attempting to get the owner of a file in Node.js on Windows. In the absence of a win32api, I thought I'd use a PowerShell command:

```
powershell -Command "(get-acl test.txt).owner"
```

This works perfectly from the command-line and from a batch file, but just hangs with Node.js `exec()`:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('powershell -Command "(get-acl test.txt).owner"', function(err,sysout,syserr) {
    console.dir(sysout);
});
```

The PowerShell process just appears to start and never terminate.

Does anybody have:

1. an idea on why the command won't return in Node.js, or preferably
2. a sane way for me to get a file owner with Node.js on Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are calling Powershell like that you need to the close the input stream. You may want to try using spawn and use `stdin.end()`.

Other option is to call `cmd /c dir /q <file>` but that output is verbose.

Comment: I used `child = exec(...); child.stdin.end();` and it work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: This answer worked for me as well.  Thank you.  One note for the reference of others experiencing this or wondering about it.  This only happens with Powershell 2 and earlier (2 ships with Windows 7) without the stdin.end() call.  For Powershell 3 and later (3 ships with Windows 8 and 5 with 10), it's not necessary and works as expected.